Filters and slicers not working as expected
I have a datamodel set up where I calculate the order intake. I have one simple stacked bar-chart showing the Orders pr, customer, and a table with the employees and corresponding orderintake.
I expected (I am very new to this), that when I clicked on an employee name, the bar chart would adjust and only show the customers with they have relation to.
If I have both on tables, it does the filtering, but not on the bar chart.
OK when table:

Bar chart: I show all the customers and grey out the ones not related.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop

It sounds like you need to create a relationship between the two tables.

For the bar chart, when clicking on the table row, you are currently cross-highlighting the selected value on the chart. To filter down to the selected bar, you will need to change the interaction behavior on the visuals.
Here is a summary of what you need to do, but this link  describes it in more detail.

Select Table visual.
Select Format Tab at top of Ribbon.
Select Edit Interactions.
On Bar Chart, select the following symbol:

Deselect Edit Interactions.

Now when you click the table, the bar chart will be filtered.

Thanks. This worked ☺️
